# angular search counter and pagination

Tags: angularjs, search, pagination

Have started coding with Angular.js in mvc and I have two problems

-The first is a issue where the search is counting the number of entry's in the info json data but not the number that is shown after the table is filtered threw a search i.e what is shown after wards if there  was a result of one result being currently shown  the label should count one.

-Also if any one knows how to do  pagination, Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
   <script>
            var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
            MyApp.controller('MyAppCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.Info = [
                  { "date":"23/09/2014","name": "john", "detail": "sssss" },
                  { "date": "27/09/2014", "name": "mary", "detail": "gggggg"  }


                ];


        </script>
        <div class="container" ng-app="MyApp">
            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 60px">
                <div class="panel panel-warning">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Home

                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        @*  left *@
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="">

                                <div class="butLay">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Reminders", "Reminders", null, new { @class = "btn btn-warning btn-md" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="butLay">



                                @Html.ActionLink("Expected customer", "Expectedcustomer", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-md" })
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        @*  Right side*@
                        <div class="pr col-md-6" ng-controller="MyAppCtrl">
                            Search:<input ng-model="query" type="text" />
                            <span class="label label-info">{{Info.length}} </span>
                            <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'date'; reverse = !reverse">Date</a></th>
                                        <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'name'; reverse = !reverse">Name</a></th>
                                        <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'detail'; reverse = !reverse">detail</a></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>


                                    <tr ng-repeat="custom in Info| filter:query | orderBy:sortField:reverse">
                                        <td>{{custom.date}}</td>
                                        <td>{{custom.name}}</td>
                                        <td>{{custom.detail}}</td>              
                                    </tr>                   
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            @*<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
                                <li class="disabled"><a href="#">«</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
                            @*</ul>*@


                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped"></table>
                </div>
                @* of panel *@
            </div>
            @*of row*@
        </div>
        @* of container *@
```

Comment: Your first point is bit unclear.

Comment: Thanks I hope I have explained it better now.

Comment: Not really, it still is confusing. Maybe you can try it another way. First be as concise as possible and then in next sentence explain the details?

Answer (score 0):

You can have another model which holds the results page wise. So eg. you have total of 55 info objects, and say you want page size (table row size to show at a time) is 20, then there will be 3 pages, with 20, 20 and 5 entries on them. The model to iterate on, in the template should be the one holding paged objects.

```
var PAGESIZE = 20;
....
....
var startIndex, stopIndex = 0, stopIndex + PAGESIZE;
$scope.pagedInfo = [];

$scope.nextPage = function(start, stop) {
    $scope.startIndex += PAGESIZE;
    $scope.stopIndex += PAGESIZE;
    $scope.pagedInfo = $scope.Info.slice($scope.startIndex, $scope.stopIndex);
}
```

And then in the template you can iterate over this `pagedInfo` instead of `Info`. You will have some button or link or any other appropriate UI element to go to next/previous pages. Add click (or any other appropriate evet)handler that will trigger the function `nextPage`. You can create a similar function for previous page too.